# Conditionally Dropping Rows If Both Variables Are NULL

Tags: python

Simple question from a Python newb.

I have a dataframe with 15+ variables and thousands of records. I want to drop the records from this dataframe when BOTH (not or) the '`DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME`' variable and '`PT_ACUITY`' variables are "Null".

I have code that will drop records from when either DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME or PT_ACUITY are NULL, but I need that "EITHER" to be an "AND".

```
TAT_v3 = TAT_v2.dropna(subset=['DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME','PT_ACUITY'],how='all')
```

I tried this line of code but got and ERROR:

CODE

```
TAT_v3 = TAT_v2.dropna((subset=['DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME','PT_ACUITY'],how='all') & (subset=['PT_ACUITY'],how='all'))
```

ERROR

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-6b23c103c833>", line 2
    TAT_v3 = TAT_v2.dropna((subset=['DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME','PT_ACUITY'],how='all') & (subset=['PT_ACUITY'],how='all'))
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.isnull()` with `all()` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME': [1, np.nan, np.nan],
    'PT_ACUITY': [2, 3, np.nan],
    'SOME_OTHER_COL': [np.nan, 4, 5]
})

cols = ['DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME', 'PT_ACUITY']  # choose columns that must all be null
results = df[~df[cols].isnull().all(axis=1)]
```

Results:

```
   DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME  PT_ACUITY  SOME_OTHER_COL
0                  1.0        2.0             NaN
1                  NaN        3.0             4.0
```

Why this works:

`df[cols].isnull()` gives a `True` or `False` value for each cell:

```
 DOCTORSEE_DATE_TIME  PT_ACUITY
0                False      False
1                 True      False
2                 True       True
```

Chaining `.all(axis=1)` onto this reduces the results down to a single `True` or `False` value for each row (`axis=0` would check column-wise instead of row-wise):

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
```

The `~` operator is used to take the inverse of the results:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

This Series of `True`, `True`, `False` is then used to slice our original DataFrame, therefore keeping only the first two rows.

Comment: Thanks - this works great! As a someone new to Python, can you please explain how the results line of code works? For example, what is ".all" and "(axis=1)" instructing?

Comment: @Raven - glad it worked, please see edit for explanation.